# How can I tell which button has accessed the context menu

Tags: android, button, contextmenu

In my soundboard app I have created a context menu using this code.

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Choose an option");
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Save as ringtone");
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Save as Notification");
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Save as Alarm");
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Exit Menu");
}


   @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    //    Global.currentsound = info.id;
        if(item.getTitle()=="Save as ringtone"){function1(item.getItemId());}
        else if(item.getTitle()=="Save as Notification"){function2(item.getItemId());}
        else if(item.getTitle()=="Save as Alarm"){function3(item.getItemId());}
        else {return false;}
    return true;
    }
```

and called on the buttons like this

Button cmenu = (Button)findViewById(R.id.s1sound1);
          registerForContextMenu(cmenu);

Now I want to pass the information for each button to the function in  the code to set the sound according to which button was pressed.  How would I do this without creating a separate context menu for each button which would be madness.

Thanks

Comment: The doc clearly tells that the `View v` which is received in `public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)` is the view for which the context menu is being built. Did you see the documentation?? So you check the id of the view like `v.getId()` and now you know which for which button/view your context menu is being built.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is stored in the "View v", Button extends View, so you have to cast it. I'm not sure, but you can check by setting a breakpoint on the

```
super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
```

line, and checking the debugger.

Comment: Yeah thanks, it is stored in the V.getId().  The android documentation can be a bit heavy at times and once you've been studying it for a while you're brain turns to mush - well mine does!